# Filtering time series dataframe for each day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large time-series `dataframe` (**pandas**), with a `datetime` index.
I'm trying to filter that `dataframe` based on the average of one column over each day.
However, when I do that I get the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def filter(Data,Variation):

   Mean = Data['column1'].resample('d').mean().dropna()

   Min = Mean * (1 - Variation)
   Max = Mean * (1 + Variation)

   Data = Data[Data['column1'] > Min]
   Data = Data[Data['column1'] < Max]

   return Data
```

I think I know what's going wrong ('`Min`' and '`Data`' are different sizes; i.e. their indices do not match), but I have no idea how to fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have resampled your DataFrame, it is a bit harder (but not impossible) to align that result (your "`Mean`") with the original data.

Instead, please consider using `groupby`, like this:

```
# example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range('2020-08-01', freq='3H', periods=20, name='date'),
    data=dict(
        x=np.random.normal(size=20),
        y=np.random.normal(size=20),
    ))

def f(g, var):
    mean = g.mean()
    return (mean * (1 - var) < g) & (g < mean * (1 + var))

selx = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).x.apply(f, var=3.0)

df.loc[selx]
```

Note: `selx` is just a `bool` timeseries; you can use it to select entire rows as per the last line above.

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for your quick reply. It looks a bit complicated for me, but hopefully if i stare at it long enough it will make sense ;-). I think i get the basic idea. At least it is nice and compact! Thanks